# Save Spark RDD to Hive Table

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark I want to save RDD objects to hive table. I am trying to use createDataFrame but that is throwing

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
 val products=sc.parallelize(evaluatedProducts.toList);
 //here products are RDD[Product]
 val productdf = hiveContext.createDataFrame(products, classOf[Product])
```

I am using Spark 1.5 version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If your Product is a class (not a case class), I suggest you transform your rdd to RDD[Tuple] before creating the DataFrame:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext

val hiveContext = new HiveContext(sc)
import hiveContext.implicits._

val productDF = products
  .map({p: Product => (p.getVal1, p.getVal2, ...)})
  .toDF("col1", "col2", ...)
```

With this approach, you will have the Product attributes as columns in the DataFrame.

Then you can create a temp table with:

```
productDF.registerTempTable("table_name")
```

or a physical table with:

```
productDF.write.saveAsTable("table_name")
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I tried as you suggested but it is returning error as 
"value toDF is not a member of org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD"



`val productdf=   products.map({ p =>(p.getcol1(), p.getCol2(),p.isValide())}).toDF("col1", "col2","col3");`

Comment: Oh, I forgot, you should call `import hiveContext.implicits._` I am going to add it to the answer.

Comment: Done as you suggested but  it is saying hiveContext.implicits._ is not found. do I need to add any jar to pom file already following dependency 
is there in pom.
`<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: I think if you update your spark-hive to match your spark version is enough: `<artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId> <version>1.5.1</version>`. Ideally, the spark-hive should always match your Spark version. If it's not enough, you can try adding the spark-sql package as well

Comment: Updated versions as mentioned below but same issue.
` error: not found: object hiveContext
[ERROR] import hiveContext.implicits._
`

`<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
   <artifactId>spark-sql_2.10</artifactId>
   <version>1.5.2</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>   
  <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-hive_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
  </dependency>`

Comment: the `import hiveContext.implicits._` must be inserted after the hiveContext creation. I edited the response, maybe it's clearer now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111138/discussion-between-daniel-de-paula-and-arvind-kumar-anugula).

Comment: @DanieldePaula: How to deal with the situation where I need to specify the hive database name along with hive table.